# Converting Long If/Then Formula into Excel Macro

Tags: vba, excel

I have a macro that relies on a lot of variables. The way I have it set up (because I know formulas better than macros) is a string of `=if(and((etc etc))` statements, and it works, but when I run it, it takes ~20 seconds. I know there's a faster way, but I'm stuck on converting the formulas into If/Then to make it faster.

The way it's set up is that if all certain criteria are met, the color populates in column N. Then, it uses an `ISNUMBER(SEARCH(""Red"",$N1))=TRUE` formula to apply conditional formatting for highlighting based on color.

All of my conditional formulas are as follows. I know there's probably a way to string them all into one, I just don't know it.

*Column F - Sum Product:* `=SUMPRODUCT((A:A=A20)*(E:E=*"N/A"*))`

VBA: `"=SUMPRODUCT((C[-5]=RC[-5])*(C[-1]=""N/A""))"`

(It actually shows the text "N/A" - it's not returning an error)

*Column G - Lookup Dollar Amount from Column P:*

`=LOOKUP(A20,O:O,P:P)`

VBA: `"=LOOKUP(RC[-6],C[8],C[9])"`

*Column K - Determine if Column E begins with a 5:*

`=IF(LEFT(C20,1)="5","Yes","No")`

VBA: `"=IF(LEFT(RC[-8],1)=""5"",""Yes"",""No"")"`

*Column M - `(Count occurances in column A) * (Count Column F > 1) * (Dollar amount in D > 0))`:*

`=SUMPRODUCT((A:A=A20)*(F:F>1)*(D:D>0))`

VBA: `"=SUMPRODUCT((C[-12]=RC[-12])*(C[-7]>1)*(C[-9]>0))"`

*Column N - Assigns color value for each conditional and applies to Column N:*

`=IF(AND((F20>1),(M20=1),(G20>0)),"Yellow",IF(AND((F20>1),(M20=1),(G20=0)),"Red",IF(AND((F20>1),(M20>1),(G20>0)),"Blue",IF(AND((K20="Yes"),(G20>0)),"Blue",IF(AND((K20="No"),(G20>0)),"Red",IF(G20<0,"Orange",IF(G20=0,"Red","Next")))))))`

VBA:
    `"=IF(AND((RC[-8]>1),(RC[-1]=1),(RC[-7]>0)),""Yellow""," & _
         "IF(AND((RC[-8]>1),(RC[-1]=1),(RC[-7]=0)),""Red""," & _
         "IF(AND((RC[-8]>1),(RC[-1]>1),(RC[-7]>0)),""Blue""," & _
         "IF(AND((RC[-3]=""Yes""),(RC[-7]>0)),""Blue""," & _
         "IF(AND((RC[-3]=""No""),(RC[-7]>0)),""Red""," & _
         "IF(RC[-7]<0,""Orange""," & _
         "IF(RC[-7]=0,""Red"",""Next"")))))))"`

Then for applying highlighting, I have:

```
Columns("A:E").Select
Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:= _
    "=ISNUMBER(SEARCH(""Blue"",$N1))=TRUE"         
Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
     With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
        .Color = 15773696
     End With
```

I know there's a way to string it all together... I'm just not sure how. There don't even have to be multiple columns... That's just how I knew how to get it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track with your VBA, but you're trying to use formula syntax in VBA code, and that's not going to work.

Change this:

```
"=IF(AND((RC[-8]>1),(RC[-1]=1),(RC[-7]>0)),""Yellow""," & _
"IF(AND((RC[-8]>1),(RC[-1]=1),(RC[-7]=0)),""Red""," & _
"IF(AND((RC[-8]>1),(RC[-1]>1),(RC[-7]>0)),""Blue""," & _
"IF(AND((RC[-3]=""Yes""),(RC[-7]>0)),""Blue""," & _
"IF(AND((RC[-3]=""No""),(RC[-7]>0)),""Red""," & _
"IF(RC[-7]<0,""Orange""," & _
"IF(RC[-7]=0,""Red"",""Next"")))))))"
```

To this:

```
Dim cel as range
offset(row,col)
set cel = ActiveCell
if cel.offset(0,-8) > 1 and cel.offset(0,-1) = 1 and cel.offset(0,-7) > 0 then
  cel.interior.color = vbYellow
elseif cel.offset(0,-8) > 1 and cel.offset(0,-1) = 1 and cel.offset(0,-7) = 0 then
  cel.interior.color = vbRed
elseif cel.offset(0,-8) > 1 and cel.offset(0,-1) > 1 and cel.offset(0,-7) > 0 then
  cel.interior.color = vbBlue
elseif ucase(cel.offset(0,-3)) = "YES" and cel.offset(0,-7) > 0 then
  cel.interior.color = vbBlue
elseif ucase(cel.offset(0,-3)) = "NO" and cel.offset(0,-7) > 0 then
  cel.interior.color = vbRed
elseif cel.offset(0,-7) < 0 then
  cel.interior.color = vbOrange
elseif cel.offset(0,-7) = 0 then
  cel.interior.color = vb.Red
End If
```

Note:

- vbOrange may not be a predefined color. You may have to specify the RGB you want to get there. This was done to get you going.
- `set cel = ActiveCell` is most likely not what you really want, but you didn't specify any code around it, so you'll have to figure out how to assign this properly yourself.
- Using this code, I think you should be able to eliminate the use of multiple columns now that you have the proper syntax for VBA instead of a formula.